# Can I make Primary Key non clustered while another index is clustered?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

In my table I have ID as primary key, it is just a meaningless unique code

as it is a primary key SQL Server 2017 made it clustered.

I have another column in my table called myTime this is a timestamp with non uinique non clustered index

Can I make the PK a non clustered and the index is clustered and how?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's as simple as using the `NONCLUSTERED` and `CLUSTERED` operators. Why didn't what you try work?

Comment: You can. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7741/when-should-a-primary-key-be-declared-non-clustered) for a good conversation about whether you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. If you already have an existing table then you need to:

1. Drop the current clustered `PRIMARY KEY`
2. Create your `CLUSTERED INDEX`
3. Create a `PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED`

For example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Test

CREATE TABLE #Test (
    ID INT, 
    TimeStamp DATETIME,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY (ID)) -- Clustered by default


ALTER TABLE #Test DROP PK_Test

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_Test_TimeStamp ON #Test (TimeStamp)

ALTER TABLE #Test ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ID)
```

The only thing that will enforce uniqueness is the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, you can still have a clustered index on repeated values, although it might raise an eyebrow for performance. See Eric's link for details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, by specifying the primary key be nonclustered.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_name PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ID);
```

You make another index clustered by specifying a clustered index.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Name   
    ON dbo.TableName (ColumnName);
```